# How can I convert a large list of numbers into JavaScript array format?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this large list of numbers: http://www.codeshare.io/MGpQ4, that I would like to convert into a JavaScript array format, so that I can check if a certain number in a function matches one of the numbers in that repsective array. Is there any tool I can use to convert all these numbers into a JS array format?

Comment: How do receive these in the code?

Comment: @tymeJV This would be a predetermined array in the code, and only one number would be received, that one number would be compared to this large array to see if there are any matches. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: @tymeJV was asking how the list of numbers was stored? Is is a string? An element on a webpage?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I copy pasted it from an excel spreadsheet, it was a long column of numbers.

Comment: Just use regex in any IDE, to replace `\n` with coma or something like this, this will help

Comment: I would write a function in your Excel spreadsheet to output the list into a javascript array format. Then paste that into your javascript file. The format you want for the array is [value1, value2, value3, ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but basically the idea is to replace line breaks by `,`. Any IDE that supports regex replacement will allow you to do this easily. You can also use virtually any programming language and use the same approach.

Here's your array literal:

```
[11450,3082,163222,57748,176966,163225,18786,163224,175522,175523,176967,176968,163226,147285,139762,147317,57793,57784,147324,147333,147336,163220,147337,147338,147339,147340,147341,147342,147343,147192,163175,163351,57847,147202,147211,147214,147215,147284,147216,152398,147218,147219,147220,147221,163397,163424,163425,163399,163427,163400,57749,163401,163402,57875,1070,171146,11452,77475,51933,156790,51920,15615,84544,153564,99754,51946,57916,51919,175521,51973,28016,176957,15620,1067,57929,57881,57882,57883,57885,57884,175524,122321,131411,122320,57886,175525,57887,122322,156789,3075,11462,51581,77411,175528,152719,51580,156801,51568,15648,51583,152553,99735,153797,51582,152554,51567,175529,51586,28017,15652,51587,57974,15628,57917,57918,57919,57920,15630,175526,175527,15629,57927,150956,122340,122341,122342,15633,11467,155198,175658,155201,175654,175655,175656,175697,175657,155200,175653,155199,175652,155203,155202,175640,163147,175648,90635,80913,80914,52762,53369,86207,175649,19255,175650,163129,125474,175651,125473,163130,125475,163131,163132,155344,175641,175642,175643,155345,155346,175644,175645,175646,155348,163148,155349,116724,175647,155347,155350,155351,82161,163149,155240,155241,155242,155243,163141,155244,155245,163142,163143,112424,163144,163145,155246,155247,155248,155249,155250,155251,155252,155253,163146,155254,112425,175638,152360,152361,152362,152363,163139,152364,152365,152366,163140,150666,152367,152368,152369,112428,172007,152345,152352,163137,152353,152354,152355,163138,152356,152357,152358,152359,112426,175639,150663,152340,152341,150664,152342,153004,4250,52357,86647,2993,152537,177649,2994,175626,167902,52365,169271,105860,105408,163582,163584,169272,52373,163583,15665,52382,179239,79720,179194,179240,179241,179242,105387,15662,90634,2996,106113,175627,1060,1059,57990,57991,15687,137084,3002,57988,11483,57989,15689,11510,11511,3001,11484,155183,15690,11507,15691,84434,313,93427,15709,11498,24087,53120,11501,11504,11505,63850,28015,175628,178962,163526,175629,105417,163525,105418,105419,105422,105440,105432,105444,16119,175630,163528,155184,155185,163537,163542,155187,177650,169277,169278,163543,169279,169280,169281,169282,178963,163549,169284,163550,166695,179243,155189,179195,179244,179245,179246,155190,169283,169276,155191,155192,166696,155195,166697,155194,155193,155197,155196,167905,3259,15720,105471,106127,163556,163552,163553,15718,98735,163560,163551,98745,175631,105516,15719,105472,106128,175633,131474,131476,105508,105509,105511,105512,105514,105515,148486,114293,105520,3263,175632,1265,4251,163573,3003,177651,168998,105559,45220,167906,45230,169285,105544,169286,169287,169288,169289,45237,15735,45238,150955,179247,45246,179196,179248,179249,179250,151486,105569,45258,175634,175635,175636,175637,163581,106129,15738,1063,15724,137085,63862,63861,11524,163587,11525,163588,11527,11523,11514,63853,163593,11521,11522,163586,63854,11530,63855,11532,45279,15746,4844,11554,3009,169001,172378,63856,11534,11535,53447,46809,15751,11517,15752,15755,15753,167903,117769,63857,15747,11536,117771,108898,11538,155206,15748,63859,63858,15754,1264,63863,11555,63864,63865,63866,155226,63867,63869,53159,15775,84275,314,169291,63852,169292,169293,169295,80600,169296,169298,169302,42526,163570,169303,3034,95672,53557,45333,55793,53548,62107,11632,63889,175759,175760,163600,163601,163602,163603,163604,163605,20287,11681,163606,163607,175805,20288,175806,74962,74963,74964,74965,74966,74967,74968,167909,962,163608,163609,167910,163610,163611,167911,163612,163613,167912,163614,163615,163616,163617,4116,14062,163618,163619,163620,163621,163622,163623,163624,163625,163626,14065,175807,163627,48559,14070,1464,74969,74970,74971,74972,74973,74974,74975,167913,960,957,163594,163595,163596,163597,163598,163599,167908,20291,175761,52383,52384,167914,52385,52386,52387,52388,155227,52389,52390,167915,52391,52392,52393,52394,155228,52395,52396,167916,52397,52401,52398,52399,155229,52400,52402,167917,52403,52404,52405,155230,52406,155231,52407,106130,48861,163628,163629,163630,48862,28022,175762,48864,48865,52408,52409,48866,52410,52411,52412,52413,155232,52414,52415,52416,52417,48867,52418,52419,52420,52421,52422,52423,52424,52425,52426,48891,52427,155233,48908,52438,52428,48881,48868,52429,167918,52430,52431,52432,52433,52434,52435,52436,52437,48886,167919,48892,48897,48902,155235,48909,52439,52440,48882,48869,52441,48887,166698,52442,52443,52444,52445,52446,52447,52448,52449,167920,48893,48898,48903,155236,48910,52450,52451,48883,48870,52452,48888,166699,52453,52454,52455,52457,52458,52459,52460,52461,167921,48894,48899,48904,155238,48911,155239,106131,965,74976,74977,74978,74979,74980,74981,74982,167922,48561,125472,156949,156950,125476,155234,125477,155237,156952,156951,170065,91247,41964,45051,41965,45052,45053,50975,50977,50976,52535,163631,41966,45054,50978,50979,50980,45055,50981,50982,50983,50985,50986,52536,50987,52537,50988,50989,50990,50991,50992,50993,50994,41967,45056,45057,14879]
```

It seems that you plan to use your array to check the existence of some values. In this case, you might be better off with an object `map` which will perform O(1) lookups.

```
{"313":true,"314":true,"957":true,"960":true,"962":true,"965":true,"1059":true,"1060":true,"1063":true,"1067":true,"1070":true,"1264":true,"1265":true,"1464":true,"2993":true,"2994":true,"2996":true,"3001":true,"3002":true,"3003":true,"3009":true,"3034":true,"3075":true,"3082":true,"3259":true,"3263":true,"4116":true,"4250":true,"4251":true,"4844":true,"11450":true,"11452":true,"11462":true,"11467":true,"11483":true,"11484":true,"11498":true,"11501":true,"11504":true,"11505":true,"11507":true,"11510":true,"11511":true,"11514":true,"11517":true,"11521":true,"11522":true,"11523":true,"11524":true,"11525":true,"11527":true,"11530":true,"11532":true,"11534":true,"11535":true,"11536":true,"11538":true,"11554":true,"11555":true,"11632":true,"11681":true,"14062":true,"14065":true,"14070":true,"14879":true,"15615":true,"15620":true,"15628":true,"15629":true,"15630":true,"15633":true,"15648":true,"15652":true,"15662":true,"15665":true,"15687":true,"15689":true,"15690":true,"15691":true,"15709":true,"15718":true,"15719":true,"15720":true,"15724":true,"15735":true,"15738":true,"15746":true,"15747":true,"15748":true,"15751":true,"15752":true,"15753":true,"15754":true,"15755":true,"15775":true,"16119":true,"18786":true,"19255":true,"20287":true,"20288":true,"20291":true,"24087":true,"28015":true,"28016":true,"28017":true,"28022":true,"41964":true,"41965":true,"41966":true,"41967":true,"42526":true,"45051":true,"45052":true,"45053":true,"45054":true,"45055":true,"45056":true,"45057":true,"45220":true,"45230":true,"45237":true,"45238":true,"45246":true,"45258":true,"45279":true,"45333":true,"46809":true,"48559":true,"48561":true,"48861":true,"48862":true,"48864":true,"48865":true,"48866":true,"48867":true,"48868":true,"48869":true,"48870":true,"48881":true,"48882":true,"48883":true,"48886":true,"48887":true,"48888":true,"48891":true,"48892":true,"48893":true,"48894":true,"48897":true,"48898":true,"48899":true,"48902":true,"48903":true,"48904":true,"48908":true,"48909":true,"48910":true,"48911":true,"50975":true,"50976":true,"50977":true,"50978":true,"50979":true,"50980":true,"50981":true,"50982":true,"50983":true,"50985":true,"50986":true,"50987":true,"50988":true,"50989":true,"50990":true,"50991":true,"50992":true,"50993":true,"50994":true,"51567":true,"51568":true,"51580":true,"51581":true,"51582":true,"51583":true,"51586":true,"51587":true,"51919":true,"51920":true,"51933":true,"51946":true,"51973":true,"52357":true,"52365":true,"52373":true,"52382":true,"52383":true,"52384":true,"52385":true,"52386":true,"52387":true,"52388":true,"52389":true,"52390":true,"52391":true,"52392":true,"52393":true,"52394":true,"52395":true,"52396":true,"52397":true,"52398":true,"52399":true,"52400":true,"52401":true,"52402":true,"52403":true,"52404":true,"52405":true,"52406":true,"52407":true,"52408":true,"52409":true,"52410":true,"52411":true,"52412":true,"52413":true,"52414":true,"52415":true,"52416":true,"52417":true,"52418":true,"52419":true,"52420":true,"52421":true,"52422":true,"52423":true,"52424":true,"52425":true,"52426":true,"52427":true,"52428":true,"52429":true,"52430":true,"52431":true,"52432":true,"52433":true,"52434":true,"52435":true,"52436":true,"52437":true,"52438":true,"52439":true,"52440":true,"52441":true,"52442":true,"52443":true,"52444":true,"52445":true,"52446":true,"52447":true,"52448":true,"52449":true,"52450":true,"52451":true,"52452":true,"52453":true,"52454":true,"52455":true,"52457":true,"52458":true,"52459":true,"52460":true,"52461":true,"52535":true,"52536":true,"52537":true,"52762":true,"53120":true,"53159":true,"53369":true,"53447":true,"53548":true,"53557":true,"55793":true,"57748":true,"57749":true,"57784":true,"57793":true,"57847":true,"57875":true,"57881":true,"57882":true,"57883":true,"57884":true,"57885":true,"57886":true,"57887":true,"57916":true,"57917":true,"57918":true,"57919":true,"57920":true,"57927":true,"57929":true,"57974":true,"57988":true,"57989":true,"57990":true,"57991":true,"62107":true,"63850":true,"63852":true,"63853":true,"63854":true,"63855":true,"63856":true,"63857":true,"63858":true,"63859":true,"63861":true,"63862":true,"63863":true,"63864":true,"63865":true,"63866":true,"63867":true,"63869":true,"63889":true,"74962":true,"74963":true,"74964":true,"74965":true,"74966":true,"74967":true,"74968":true,"74969":true,"74970":true,"74971":true,"74972":true,"74973":true,"74974":true,"74975":true,"74976":true,"74977":true,"74978":true,"74979":true,"74980":true,"74981":true,"74982":true,"77411":true,"77475":true,"79720":true,"80600":true,"80913":true,"80914":true,"82161":true,"84275":true,"84434":true,"84544":true,"86207":true,"86647":true,"90634":true,"90635":true,"91247":true,"93427":true,"95672":true,"98735":true,"98745":true,"99735":true,"99754":true,"105387":true,"105408":true,"105417":true,"105418":true,"105419":true,"105422":true,"105432":true,"105440":true,"105444":true,"105471":true,"105472":true,"105508":true,"105509":true,"105511":true,"105512":true,"105514":true,"105515":true,"105516":true,"105520":true,"105544":true,"105559":true,"105569":true,"105860":true,"106113":true,"106127":true,"106128":true,"106129":true,"106130":true,"106131":true,"108898":true,"112424":true,"112425":true,"112426":true,"112428":true,"114293":true,"116724":true,"117769":true,"117771":true,"122320":true,"122321":true,"122322":true,"122340":true,"122341":true,"122342":true,"125472":true,"125473":true,"125474":true,"125475":true,"125476":true,"125477":true,"131411":true,"131474":true,"131476":true,"137084":true,"137085":true,"139762":true,"147192":true,"147202":true,"147211":true,"147214":true,"147215":true,"147216":true,"147218":true,"147219":true,"147220":true,"147221":true,"147284":true,"147285":true,"147317":true,"147324":true,"147333":true,"147336":true,"147337":true,"147338":true,"147339":true,"147340":true,"147341":true,"147342":true,"147343":true,"148486":true,"150663":true,"150664":true,"150666":true,"150955":true,"150956":true,"151486":true,"152340":true,"152341":true,"152342":true,"152345":true,"152352":true,"152353":true,"152354":true,"152355":true,"152356":true,"152357":true,"152358":true,"152359":true,"152360":true,"152361":true,"152362":true,"152363":true,"152364":true,"152365":true,"152366":true,"152367":true,"152368":true,"152369":true,"152398":true,"152537":true,"152553":true,"152554":true,"152719":true,"153004":true,"153564":true,"153797":true,"155183":true,"155184":true,"155185":true,"155187":true,"155189":true,"155190":true,"155191":true,"155192":true,"155193":true,"155194":true,"155195":true,"155196":true,"155197":true,"155198":true,"155199":true,"155200":true,"155201":true,"155202":true,"155203":true,"155206":true,"155226":true,"155227":true,"155228":true,"155229":true,"155230":true,"155231":true,"155232":true,"155233":true,"155234":true,"155235":true,"155236":true,"155237":true,"155238":true,"155239":true,"155240":true,"155241":true,"155242":true,"155243":true,"155244":true,"155245":true,"155246":true,"155247":true,"155248":true,"155249":true,"155250":true,"155251":true,"155252":true,"155253":true,"155254":true,"155344":true,"155345":true,"155346":true,"155347":true,"155348":true,"155349":true,"155350":true,"155351":true,"156789":true,"156790":true,"156801":true,"156949":true,"156950":true,"156951":true,"156952":true,"163129":true,"163130":true,"163131":true,"163132":true,"163137":true,"163138":true,"163139":true,"163140":true,"163141":true,"163142":true,"163143":true,"163144":true,"163145":true,"163146":true,"163147":true,"163148":true,"163149":true,"163175":true,"163220":true,"163222":true,"163224":true,"163225":true,"163226":true,"163351":true,"163397":true,"163399":true,"163400":true,"163401":true,"163402":true,"163424":true,"163425":true,"163427":true,"163525":true,"163526":true,"163528":true,"163537":true,"163542":true,"163543":true,"163549":true,"163550":true,"163551":true,"163552":true,"163553":true,"163556":true,"163560":true,"163570":true,"163573":true,"163581":true,"163582":true,"163583":true,"163584":true,"163586":true,"163587":true,"163588":true,"163593":true,"163594":true,"163595":true,"163596":true,"163597":true,"163598":true,"163599":true,"163600":true,"163601":true,"163602":true,"163603":true,"163604":true,"163605":true,"163606":true,"163607":true,"163608":true,"163609":true,"163610":true,"163611":true,"163612":true,"163613":true,"163614":true,"163615":true,"163616":true,"163617":true,"163618":true,"163619":true,"163620":true,"163621":true,"163622":true,"163623":true,"163624":true,"163625":true,"163626":true,"163627":true,"163628":true,"163629":true,"163630":true,"163631":true,"166695":true,"166696":true,"166697":true,"166698":true,"166699":true,"167902":true,"167903":true,"167905":true,"167906":true,"167908":true,"167909":true,"167910":true,"167911":true,"167912":true,"167913":true,"167914":true,"167915":true,"167916":true,"167917":true,"167918":true,"167919":true,"167920":true,"167921":true,"167922":true,"168998":true,"169001":true,"169271":true,"169272":true,"169276":true,"169277":true,"169278":true,"169279":true,"169280":true,"169281":true,"169282":true,"169283":true,"169284":true,"169285":true,"169286":true,"169287":true,"169288":true,"169289":true,"169291":true,"169292":true,"169293":true,"169295":true,"169296":true,"169298":true,"169302":true,"169303":true,"170065":true,"171146":true,"172007":true,"172378":true,"175521":true,"175522":true,"175523":true,"175524":true,"175525":true,"175526":true,"175527":true,"175528":true,"175529":true,"175626":true,"175627":true,"175628":true,"175629":true,"175630":true,"175631":true,"175632":true,"175633":true,"175634":true,"175635":true,"175636":true,"175637":true,"175638":true,"175639":true,"175640":true,"175641":true,"175642":true,"175643":true,"175644":true,"175645":true,"175646":true,"175647":true,"175648":true,"175649":true,"175650":true,"175651":true,"175652":true,"175653":true,"175654":true,"175655":true,"175656":true,"175657":true,"175658":true,"175697":true,"175759":true,"175760":true,"175761":true,"175762":true,"175805":true,"175806":true,"175807":true,"176957":true,"176966":true,"176967":true,"176968":true,"177649":true,"177650":true,"177651":true,"178962":true,"178963":true,"179194":true,"179195":true,"179196":true,"179239":true,"179240":true,"179241":true,"179242":true,"179243":true,"179244":true,"179245":true,"179246":true,"179247":true,"179248":true,"179249":true,"179250":true}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to split this list. You need to add something like coma or space at the end of your lines.

```
string.split(/* your delimetter */);
```

`string` here is your list in vaid JS format.

If you show real code, i could answer better.

Comment: Simply encapsulating the list of numbers within a single set of quotes and escaping new lines with \ is impossible in javascript - it does not allow for multi-line string declarations.

Comment: well, my Chrome interpretate it like a string without any spaces between lines, so not helpfull anyway

Answer (score 1):

Like plalx said, any IDE with regex replacement can do it.

As an alternative, you can chech http://www.regexr.com/

And use something like `/([0-9]+)/g` for matching those numbers and then use a substitution like `$1,`

Then just add your [].

Answer (score 0):

In your Excel spreadsheet, create a cell with a function that pulls all the numbers in the list into a javascript array format. Something like:

```
=CONCATENATE("[", TRANSPOSE(A1:A700 & ”, “) ,"]")
```

Something like that should create a new cell with all your list values in a single, comma delimited string, enclosed by `[]`.

Copy the entire string and place it in your javascript file as a variable.

```
var list = [value1, value2, value3, ...];
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it.